# Proper Fetch call for Delete using json-server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

Im using json-server to create a fake server and Im fetching stuff from it. The GET works correctly, so does the POST when I add to the JSON, however I get a 404 error when i DELETE anything. The formed url seems to be correct, and it does point to the very JSON I want to delete, however it still gives me a 404. Any ideas?

```
deleteService = () => {
    return fetch(
      `http://${delete_url}/services?id=${this.props.data.id}&domain=${
        this.props.data.domain
      }`,
      {
        method: "DELETE"
      }
    )
      .then(res => res.json());
  };
```

Example of my JSON

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "domain": "Domain1",
      "service_name": "Get Users",
      "service_version": "1.0.0",
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/abc/def",
      "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
      "host": "test.com",
      "response": "200"
    }
}
```

Error

> DELETE http://localhost:3100/services?id=1&domain=Domain1 404 (Not
>   Found)

Even though the URL correctly exists on my JSON..

Comment: You probably don't support that action in your handler, I don't know what you are using for a backend but you probably don't have the delete route specified.

Comment: Im using json-server from 'https://github.com/typicode/json-server'. The docs say that it supports delete out of the box..

Comment: Does a DELETE request to `http://localhost:3100/services/1` work?

Comment: Yes that works! So am I just doing the calls wrong? How can I add both the id and domain ? Just use the variables ?

Comment: So only using /${id} works and I know ids are supposed to be unique so it shouldnt really have a problem, but can I still use the ${domain} as well? Adding the domain gives 404 again..

Answer (score -1):

try using axios

```
 await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3100/servicess/${this.props.data.id}`)
```

and in the function pass the id as a param