# FETCH/AXIOS DELETE not working with json-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api, json-server

I know this problem is repeated, but I cannot find the answer to it.

My problem is similar to this one:

[Proper Fetch call for Delete using json-server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503687/proper-fetch-call-for-delete-using-json-server)

I also used fetch and axios both like this:

```
await  axios({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: `http://localhost:8000/${measurementData.toolType}?LesionNamingNumber=${measurementData.lesionNamingNumber}`
  });



await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/${measurementData.toolType}?lesionNamingNumber=${measurementData.lesionNamingNumber}`, {
    method: 'DELETE'
  }).then(data => {
    console.log('data deleted');
  });
```

I am still getting this error:

> 'DELETE http://localhost:8000/EllipticalRoi?lesionNamingNumber=1 404 (Not Found)'.

But I can see the data after visiting this URL.

My react is running on localhost:3000

I am using JSON-server with react.

JSON-SERVER version - 0.16.3

Any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: What does your server code look like? Make sure you have "DELETE" in the methods list for this URL you're calling, also that you can bring in HTTP/1.1 methods (some can only take GET and POST because it's HTTP/1.0).

Comment: I am not sure where I can search for it as I am new to this. I am using OHIF, an open-source project, and here is one server.js file: https://github.com/OHIF/Viewers/tree/master/platform/core/src/redux/reducers.
Where can I also check the list of URLs?

Comment: What you sent me doesn't look like server code, but rather your redux state on the client side. I'm talking about what's running on localhost:8000 . You should have a server route to `/EllipticalRoi`, ensuring there isn't one on the client side to clash (React checks client side before trying to hit proxies, which is why I always preface server routes with `/api`).

Comment: localhost:8000: Congrats!
You're successfully running JSON Server
✧*｡٩(ˊᗜˋ*)و✧*｡

Resources
/EllipticalRoi 3x
To access and modify resources, you can use any HTTP method:

GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE OPTIONS

Comment: Again, that does not answer the question. Where is your server code, what methods is the server's router actively looking for and to which methods?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I miss interpreting your question.
If I understood correctly now then I am running the json-server using this method: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server/v/0.11.2#alternative-port.
I am not using any static file server method: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server/v/0.11.2#static-file-server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230882/discussion-between-ragu-and-user3832673).